# How to get the JPA child class id in parent class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

i am trying to associate two entity classes . The Document class i cannot really change it because its used in lot of other places in the application . But i can play around ICError  class.
I am trying to get id of the Document  into my ICError class field.

```
public class ICError {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ1")
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ1", sequenceName = "SEQ_IC_ERROR" , allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name="ID")
private Long id;

String documentId; // i want to map Document id into this field.

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "icError" , orphanRemoval = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Document document;

}


public class Document {

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUIDGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUIDGenerator")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
UUID id;

@OneToOne
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "id",referencedColumnName = "id")
ICError icError;

}

Service Class 

//Document document = new Document();
//document.setId(UUID.randomUUID());// Getting error saying detached entity passed to persist, 
//if i remove the cascade = CascadeType.ALL its not even inserting the record. and dont want to 
//use the UUID.randomUUID() because entity class already have generator.

//Below is the one am trying. This is inserting the record but 
//documentId is null.
ICError icError = new ICError(documentId, new Document());// how i will get the documentId to 
//ICError class . 
repo.save(icError);
```

Comment: looks like there's something wrong with your mapping: you have `@OneToOne` in the `ICError` class, but `@ManyToOne` in the `Document` class. do you want the document to have multiple errors or only one error?

Comment: Sorry , that was a typo mistake , I want oneToOne only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the benefit of what you are trying to do here, but you could save Document first which will give you the documentId and then set ICError.documentId & ICError.document fields

Comment: That will fix the issue , but will have one extra DB call . I am trying to avoid it. If we can map it it can be saved in a single DB call